# Как конвертировать файл word в PDF/XPS и в Adobe PDF через код на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word

Имеется документ word, необходимо чтобы при запуске программы определенный документ конвертировался в указанное расширение.  Как так сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python  подойдет?

Comment: Можно привести пример с объяснением на русском?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант (перед этим только нужно **pip install docx2pdf**):

```
from docx2pdf import convert

convert("input.docx")
```

И ваш файл (лежащий рядом с файлом скрипта) **input.docx** превратиться в **output.pdf** (и так же будет рядом с файлом скрипта).